# show statement_timeout as millis in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a view that will return the numeric value of the current `statement_timeout` in milliseconds. However, the result of the `SHOW` command is human-readable and may have different suffixes such as `min` and `ms`:

```
begin transaction;
set local statement_timeout = 120000; 
show  statement_timeout;
--------------
'2min'
```

How to retrieve the raw, untranslated value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can query `pg_settings` directly:

```
select setting
from pg_settings
where name = 'statement_timeout'
```